# Made a git commit but for some reason it shows the user as www on github

Tags: git, github

Cloned my own repository from github and made a commit locally, setting the author as blank on my commit. Then I pushed the commit to github logging in through my actual account. But now on github the committer is "www" clicking on which brings me to a user page of "www" with no commits. It looks like a legitimate user because they have followers that I don't have. Is this expected behaviour? What happened?

Comment: What do `git config user.name` and `git config user.email` log?

Answer (score 1):

The thing that happened is your git username or email matched the account.

One of the reasons below might caused the problem.

- Your email address is not set in Git.
- Your email address might match the `www` account.
- Your committer name might be set to `www`

Also see [here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/) to set your Git username and email. ([click here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190209222459/https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/) if the link didn't work.)

Comment: Wait so can I just impersonate anyone on git committing to my repository?

Comment: @trallgorm As long as you know the e mail address (or the github noreply user address) and the username you can. But the commit will not be signed.